# How to format my data with modified model in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hello i am supossed to change the model to the one below but now my code doesnt work and i cant figure out how to format the data with the model provided . Any help appreciated.

here is the api: https://archive-api.open-meteo.com/v1/era5?latitude=51.51&longitude=-0.13&start_date=2005-08-25&end_date=2005-08-25&hourly=temperature_2m,relativehumidity_2m,dewpoint_2m,apparent_temperature,surface_pressure,precipitation,rain,cloudcover,windspeed_10m,winddirection_10m,soil_temperature_0_to_7cm&timezone=Europe%2FLondon

in the component ngOnInit subscription i am making variable for each array of data from the api (modifying some arrays there like time,precipitation and wind direction) and then pushing new WeatherDataItem object with those variables  to empty array weatherData: WeatherDataItem[] = [] from which i am filling table columns in html

```
weatherData: WeatherDataItem[] = [];
…
…
this.weatherService.getWeather()
...
...
 .subscribe({
        next: (historicalWeatherData) => {
          const temperatures = historicalWeatherData.hourly.temperature_2m;
          const times = historicalWeatherData.hourly.time.map((time) =>
            this.datePipe.transform(time, 'shortTime')
          );
          const humidities = historicalWeatherData.hourly.relativehumidity_2m;
          const windSpeeds = historicalWeatherData.hourly.windspeed_10m;
          const airPressures = historicalWeatherData.hourly.surface_pressure;
          const windDirections =
            historicalWeatherData.hourly.winddirection_10m.map((item) =>
              this.checkWindDirection(item)
            );
          const precipitations = historicalWeatherData.hourly.precipitation.map(
            (item) => {
              if (item > 0) {
                return new Rain(item, true);
              }
              return new Rain(item, false);
            }
          );
          const cloudcover = historicalWeatherData.hourly.cloudcover;
          const soilTemperatures =
            historicalWeatherData.hourly.soil_temperature_0_to_7cm;
          temperatures.forEach((value, i) => {
            this.weatherData.push(
              new WeatherDataItem(
                value,
                times[i],
                humidities[i],
                windSpeeds[i],
                airPressures[i],
                windDirections[i],
                precipitations[i],
                cloudcover[i],
                soilTemperatures[i]
              )
            );
          });
...
...
...
```

here is the model i am using right now for weatherData

```
export class WeatherDataItem {
  constructor(
    public temperature: string,
    public time: string,
    public humidity: string,
    public wind: string,
    public pressure: string,
    public direction: string,
    public precipitation: Rain,
    public cloudcover: string,
    public soilTemperature: string
  ) {}
}
```

and i am supposed to use this model because the above one apparently has too many arguments in constructor but dont know how to implement that because now in the component  i am getting error: expecting 1 argument but got 9

```
export class WeatherDataItem {
  temperature: number;
  time: string;
  humidity: number;
  wind: number;
  pressure: number;
  direction: string;
  precipitation: Rain;
  cloudcover: number;
  soilTemperature: number;

  constructor(inputData: Object)  // type WeatherDataItem ? or what should be the type here
{
    (this.temperature = inputData.temperature),
      (this.time = inputData.time),
      (this.humidity = inputData.humidity),
      (this.wind = inputData.wind),
      (this.pressure = inputData.pressure),
      (this.direction = inputData.direction),
      (this.precipitation = inputData.precipitation),
      (this.cloudcover = inputData.cloudcover),
      (this.soilTemperature = inputData.soilTemperature);
  }
}
```

i tried this in component but no luck

```
const inputData = [
            temperatures,
            times,
            humidities,
            windSpeeds,
            airPressures,
            windDirections,
            precipitations,
            cloudcover,
            soilTemperatures,
          ];
          this.weatherData.push(new WeatherDataItem(inputData));
```

html

```
 <p-table
[value]="weatherData"
...
...
...
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-weather>
        <tr>
          <td field="time">{{weather.time}}</td>
          <td field="temperature">{{weather.temperature}}&deg;C</td>
          <td field="humidity">{{weather.humidity}}%</td>
          <td field="wind">{{weather.wind}} km/h</td>
          <td field="pressure">{{weather.pressure}} hPa</td>
          <td field="direction">{{weather.direction}}</td>
          <td field="precipitation.didRain">{{weather.precipitation.amount}} mm</td>
          <td field="cloudcover">{{weather.cloudcover}}%</td>
          <td field="soilTemperature">{{weather.soilTemperature}}&deg;C</td>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
```

Comment: how the Rain class looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works when I've added it, maybe you've got a typo somewhere. I had to add the mapping to string when creating the new `WeatherDataItem` in your OnInit function

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qchu4z

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, yes it works for me too with the WeatherDataItem model u used there but i am supposed to make it work with the model i updated there on stackblitz please check.. i also updated the Rain model there https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kjfo8a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fweather%2Fweather.type.ts